# Distributions bounded on both sides

Tags: probability, distributions

Similar questions to this

[Common name for distributions that are bounded on one side](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/113273/common-name-for-distributions-that-are-bounded-on-one-side)

I am looking for common name or an exhaustive list of which distributions are bounded on both sides [0,1].   This is because my data is similar to this (cannot be less than 0 and greater than 100). I need to fit a distribution to this data. In order to do this, I need to firs find a list of distributions that are bounded on both sides and try them one by one to see which distribution closely resembles my data.

Comment: There is no exhaustive list. Think of this: any nonnegative function with finite integral on [0,1] can be a density function. You can't name them all.

Comment: Okay. Is there a list of some commonly used family of distribution that I can fit to a bounded dataset

Comment: Have a look at beta regression and if you analyze your data in R, the `betareg` [package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/betareg/vignettes/betareg.pdf) is very useful. Also searching for beta regression on this site will give you a lot of examples. Note however, that if your data has zero and ones, the analysis won't run. In this case, you can scale your data so it will fall between 0 and 1. There is a scaling procedure mentioned in the PDF (page 3, 3rd paragraph).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There can't be an exhaustive list. However, you can find a list of some continuous densities with bounds in wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions#Supported_on_a_bounded_interval

Also, remember that you can take any distribution and bound it in an interval. These are called truncated distributions, e.g. see [truncated normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution).

Comment: Thank you. I was not aware of the truncated distribution.  I will read around it.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [kernel functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(statistics)). When a kernel satisfies $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty K(x)\,\mathrm dx = 1,$$ it results in a probability density function.