# How to generate samples of ARIMA(p,d,q) model within an interval?

Tags: time-series, arima, simulation, bounds

I am want to generate samples from an ARIMA(p,d,q) or ARMA(p,q) model. There is a [Python Package](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/examples/notebooks/generated/tsa_arma_1.html) to generate ARMA samples. The problem is that I want to generate scenarios for demand which should be non-negative and also, usually there is an upper bound for demand. I would be thankful if can help me with how to generate samples from ARIMA(p,d,q) which fall in the interval [l,u].

Answer (score 0):

The first question is whether a model from the ARIMA class is appropriate for your data generating process. But I will leave it aside in this answer and only address your original question.

---

An ARIMA model will generally produce an anbounded sequence. One way to bound it would be to only use an MA model combined with a bounded error distribution (e.g. uniform, but not only; see ["Distributions bounded on both sides"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/333452) for more ideas). If your error term $\varepsilon$ is bounded as $\varepsilon\in[a,b]$ and your MA(q) model is
$$
y_t=\theta_0+\varepsilon_t+\theta_1\varepsilon_{t-1}+\dots+\theta_q\varepsilon_{t-q},
$$
then $y_t$ is bounded as follows:
$$
\theta_0-\xi 
\leq y_t\leq
\theta_0+\xi
$$
where $$
\xi=a\sum_{i=1}^q\min\{\theta_i,0\}+b\sum_{i=1}^q\max\{\theta_i,0\}.
$$
If you want $y_t$ to be bounded between $l$ and $u$, you need to solve
$\theta_0-\xi=l$ and $\theta_0+\xi=u$ for $a$ and $b$.

---

Another way of bounding ARIMA processes with AR terms and/or with unbounded error distributions would be to transform them, but that would no longer be an ARIMA process. The transformation could be done by using a cumulative density function (CDF) of a random variable with unbounded support. This would produce a number between $0$ and $1$. (Think logistic regression or probit model.) Then you could multiply the result by a scale parameter $u-l$ and add a location parameter $l$ to make them lie within $(u,l)$.

How would fit such a model in practice? You would take your raw data and do the opposite transformation. First, subtract $l$ and divide by $u-l$, then apply an inverse CDF to make them lie in $(\infty,+\infty)$ where they can be modelled with an arbitrary ARIMA. Then use the fitted model to do predictions or simulations and then transform these back to $[l,u]$ as described in the preceding paragraph.

Comment: I am not 100% sure if I defined $\xi$ correctly, but it should not be too difficult to check and fix that if needed.